# Is it possible to store 10 million numbers in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I want to know how many numbers can you store in array?

```
srand (time(NULL));
int array[10000000];
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % 10000000) + 1;
}
```

Every time I want to store 10.000.000 numbers in array my program crashed (Eclipse). I even tryed Visual Studio and it crashed to.

So i want to know how many numbers can I store in array or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Depends on your stack size. Also, you should be using the `<random>` header for pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Is it just me that reads this question and envisions Dr. Evil saying "I want to store 10 MILLION NUMBERS" while twisting his finger at the corner of his mouth? http://i.imgur.com/h27654L.jpg

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can store as many numbers as you have memory for, but you cannot do it like that.  The reason your program crashes is that you are using an "automatic" variable, which is allocated on the "stack."  The stack is much more limited in size than the "heap" typically, so using automatic variables of such large size may result in a...wait for it...

STACK OVERFLOW!

Instead, try this:

```
int* array = new int[10000000];
```

Then after using it:

```
delete[] array;
```

Step two will be to learn about smart pointers; you can use something like `boost::scoped_array` for this case, but there are lots of options depending on which libraries you prefer (or if you have C++11).

If you have C++11 you can use "RAII" to avoid needing to remember when and where to call delete.  Just do this to allocate the array:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> array(new int[10000000]);
```

Or just use a vector, which always allocates its contents dynamically ("on the heap", loosely speaking):

```
std::vector<int> array(10000000); // 10000000 elements, all zero
```

Comment: Now that you have said that, how could you implement and call this array in a function later on, "print_out_array(array)", and also how would you even have the array written in the code of the function like "void print_out_array (int  array[10000000]) {..." ?

Answer (score 7):

The language is more than capable of storing 10,000,000 values in an array.  The problem here though is you've declared the 10,000,000 elements to exist on the stack.  The size of the stack is implementation dependent but most stacks simply don't have enough space for that many elements.  The heap is a much better place for such an array

```
int* array = new int[10000000];
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % 10000000) + 1;
}
...
delete[] array;
```

Comment: But how do you call this array in a function later or actually how would you even have the array written in the function "void print_array (int  array[10000000]) {... "?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple places you could put your array in memory. The most common difference we think about is the *stack* and the *heap*.

The stack is how the computer keeps track of which function you're in, how to return from the function, and the local variables. It is often of limited size. The exact limit depends on your platform, and perhaps how you compiled your program.

The heap is another area in memory, where the compiler usually stores things you've allocated with the `new` keyword. This is often much larger, and capable of storing a big array such as yours. The downside to keeping things on the heap is that you have to remember to `delete` them at the appropriate time.

In your example, you are declaring a 10,000,000 element array on the stack. If you wanted to declare that array on the heap, you would do it like this:

```
srand (time(NULL));
int* array = new int[10000000];
for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % 10000000) + 1;
}

//Sometime later...
delete[] array;
```

However, C++ gives us better tools for this. If you want a big array, use `std::vector`.

```
srand (time(NULL));
std::vector<int> array(10000000);
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    array[i] = (rand() % 10000000) + 1;
}
```

Now, your `std::vector` is on the stack, but the memory it controls is on the heap. You don't have to remember to delete it later, and your program doesn't crash.

Comment: There are actually more than two: 1) Global variable section, which is neither stack nor heap.  2) Constant data area, which may be read-only memory, often it is the same area as the executable. 3) Stack, which many compilers use to store function local variables. 4) Heap, which many compilers use to store dynamically allocated variables.  5) Files or external memory.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMatthews! I hadn't thought of those. I edited the post to be a little more clear.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Cannot we make array static , i tried it work , is there any downsides  , apart from that it has to be of fixed size determined before running?

Comment: @SurajJain: The array can be made global, file local scope or static.  Some implementations have smaller limits for a static array than one that uses dynamic memory.

Comment: @SurajJain:  The amount of memory available and how the implementation (compiler) and operating system allocate memory is platform dependent and not language dependent.  Open up some documents on various compilers and you will see.  Check their limits for stack variables, automatic variables and dynamic variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank You Sir.